# Print result from dbus object

Tags: python, dbus

I want to print the result from the dbus.

In the command line i run this:

```
busctl introspect org.freedesktop.systemd1 /org/freedesktop/systemd1 org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties
```

And i get some results.

I try with python but no luck to print the results.

```
import dbus
bus = dbus.SystemBus()
eth0 = bus.get_object('org.freedesktop.NetworkManager',
                      '/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/eth0')
eth0_dev_iface = dbus.Interface(eth0,
    dbus_interface='org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Devices')
props = eth0_dev_iface.getProperties()
```

But i get this error:

> dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such method 'getProperties'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was pretty aggravating. The interface is kinda crazy.

Try this:

```
import dbus
bus = dbus.SystemBus()
eth0 = bus.get_object('org.freedesktop.NetworkManager',
                      '/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/eth0')

# Here's where we change things
eth0_dev_iface = dbus.Interface(eth0,
    dbus_interface='org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties')
eth0_dev_iface.GetAll('org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Devices')
```

Now why doesn't the documentation example code work as documented? That's a great question... The code above however, works fine.